# Variable holding a number constantly without being able to edit the value

Tags: c#

How do I make so a integer type of variable holds a number constantly through the whole time the game is running, without being able to edit the value inside?

Comment: You need to specify more context, like what language you're programming in.

Comment: Little details like what language you are talking about are needed before anyone can answer this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a constant:

```
public const int SomeValue = 123;
```

or a [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) instance field which could only be assigned in the constructor of the class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public readonly int SomeValue;
    public Foo()
    {
        SomeValue = 123;
    }
}
```

or you could use a static readonly field (which need to be initialized either in a static constructor or inline):

```
public static readonly int SomeValue = 123;
```

or you could use a property with a private setter allowing you to set the value only from inside the containing class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int SomeValue { get; private set; }
    public Foo()
    {
        SomeValue = 123;
    }
}
```

or you could implement the [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) if you want this value to be initialized only once for the entire lifetime of the application.

So, yes, based on what exactly you are trying to achieve there are many ways to achieve it. Depending on the specific context some methods might be preferred than others.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices here.

One is to use a **constant**.

```
 const float pi = 3.14f;
 const int r = 123;
 const string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Products]";
```

Another is to use a **readonly variable**.

```
  public readonly int y = 25; 
  public readonly int z;
  public static readonly uint l1 = (uint) DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

**What's the difference**? A `const` can only be initialized when it is declared. That is, the value is set when the variable is declared, and it cannot be changed.

A `readonly` field can be initialized when it is declared OR in a constructor.
So, while a `const` field is a compile-time constant, the `readonly` field can be used for runtime constants.